# Mover una imagen para conseguir el area deseada dentro de un contenedor

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Requiero hacer una portada como la de facebook en mi sitio web, para que cuando seleccione una imagen pueda ajustar el área visualizada antes de subirla a la base de datos, pero no tengo idea de cuál plugin puedo implementar. Estaba intenando con croppie.js, sin embargo no tengo mucho control dentro de la librería. Espero y me puedan ayudar con mi inconveniente. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

esto te genera portadas de Facebook no si te sirve pero te lo comparto [enlace](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/)

**puedes cambiar la pagina en este input**
[image: url]

**debes darle al botón**
[image: a]

**seguir las indicaciones que muestra**
[image: a]

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar cropper.js tiene varias opciones configurables https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/